# Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_props$field.open')] in Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I try to validate the schema with formik and yup. Both are validating the schema correctly but I try to submit the form its throws an error. I use textinput and dropdown.

**DropDown**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

const DropDown = (props) => {
  const {
    field: {
      open,
      value,
      items,
      setOpen,
      setValue,
      setItems,
      name,
      onChangeItem,
      placeholder,
      style,
      dropDownMaxHeight,
      onBlur,
    },
    form: { errors, touched, setFieldTouched },
    ...inputProps
  } = { ...props };
  const hasError = errors[name] && touched[name];
  return (
    <View>
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        items={items}
        onBlur={() => {
          setFieldTouched(name);
          onBlur(name);
        }}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setItems}
        onChangeItem={onChangeItem}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        containerStyle={styles.height}
        style={[styles.color, hasError && styles.errorInput, { ...style }]}
        itemStyle={styles.item}
        dropDownStyle={styles.color}
        dropDownMaxHeight={dropDownMaxHeight}
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {hasError && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors[name]}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};
```

**TextInput**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput as Input } from 'react-native-paper';

const CustomInput = (props) => {
  const {
    field: { name, onBlur, onChange, value, keyboardType },
    form: { errors, touched, setFieldTouched },
    ...inputProps
  } = { ...props };

  const hasError = errors[name] && touched[name];

  return (
    <View>
      <Input
        style={[styles.textInput, hasError && styles.errorInput]}
        value={value}
        mode="outlined"
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        onChangeText={(text) => onChange(name)(text)}
        onBlur={() => {
          setFieldTouched(name);
          onBlur(name);
        }}
        theme={{
          roundness: 5,
          colors: {
            primary: '#00E676',
            underlineColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: '#00E676',
            placeholder: 'black',
          },
          fonts: {
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-SemiBold',
          },
        }}
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {hasError && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors[name]}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};
```

If I only use textinput then it's working. but not with dropdown.

**Formik**

```
 validationSchema={newSubscriptionValidator}
      initialValues={{
        name: '',
        description: '',
        renewal: '',
}
}
 onSubmit={(values) => navigation.navigate('SubConfig')}
```

**Schema**

```
export const newSubscriptionValidator = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required('name is required'),
  description: yup.string().required('description is required'),
  renewal: yup.string().required('renewal is required'),
});
```

Why it throws an error for dropdown?

Thanks!!